# I have an issue with casting Player to a MyPlayer

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

Hello I started learning to code minecraft bukkit plugins just few days a go, so please don't blame me if my issue is stiupid. I want to create a new MyPlayer class that will be Player subclass. I have already figured out that Player's root is org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.entity.CraftPlayer so I can make somethink like this: `public class OticPlayer extends org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.entity.CraftPlayer`. I want MyClass to contain all of his parent methods, but add some it's own. The problem is when i use: `Bukkit.getPlayerExact(arg3[1])` it return the reference to a Player type object. I have a Lobby class with method `addPlayer(MyPlayer arg0)`, so I need a reference to the MyPlayer type object, not Player. When I will try to cast a Player type reference to MyPlayer, it's throws an exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.entity.CraftPlayer cannot be cast to me.gtddd.my.MyPlayer`. I need to pass MyPlayer type reference to the addPlayer() method, because I want to make some kind of stats system (K/D/A), each of these stats must be a pool accesable, by MyPlayer type object. So how can I cast Player to MyPlayer? Example code that generates this problem:

```
package test;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import me.gtddd.otic.OticPlayer;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.EntityPlayer;

public class MyPlayer extends org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.entity.CraftPlayer {
    public MyPlayer(CraftServer server, EntityPlayer entity) {
        super(server, entity);
    }

    int kills = 0;
    int deaths = 0;
    int assists = 0;

    public int getKda() {
        return kills/deaths/assists;
    }
}

public class Lobby {
    MyPlayer[] players = new MyPlayer[10];

    public void addPlayer(MyPlayer arg0) {
        players[players.length] = arg0;
    }

    public MyPlayer getPlayer(int slot) {
        return players[slot-1];
    }
}




public class Main extends JavaPlugin { 
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        Lobby lobby1 = new Lobby();
        MyPlayer player = (MyPlayer) Bukkit.getPlayerExact("Notch");
        lobby1.addPlayer(player);
        System.out.println(lobby1.getPlayer(1).getKda());
    }
}
```

I looked lot to find the answer, but I was not able to find anythink what would satisfy me. From top: Thanks for all answers! If somethink is unclear ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of `extending` a `Player`**, you should create a `Wrapper` around Bukkit's Player Object, more specifically wrapping the Player's `Name` or `UUID` (recommended) as it's **not possible to edit Bukkit's Player instances without a lot of effort**, it's implementation is very obscure, and you won't be able to include your `MyPlayer` in Bukkit's server.

---

So, for example, you could create a MyPlayer as following:

```
class MyPlayer {
    private String playerName;

    public MyPlayer(Player player) {
        playerName = player.getDisplayName();   //Something like this to store the player
    }
    //More of your code, for example counting the kills

    public Player recoverPlayerObject() {
         return Bukkit.getPlayer(playerName);
   }
```

And if you want to do things like adding a kill to the player, and then teleporting him, you could use your `MyPlayer` instance to modify your players' attributes, and using the `recoverPlayerObject` if you need to interact directly with Bukkit `Player` object.

---

For more information on Wrapper/Decorator, Iluwatar has a very nice [Github repository](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/decorator) about Design Patterns, including the Decorator.